# How to apply DSCP fields on SYNC-ACK packets using setsocketopt function

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a TCP client and server running on Linux platform. Basically using setsocketopt I am able to mark SYNC packets. But I don't know how to apply DSCP priority to SYNC-ACK packet. I can set correct DSCP once socket is accepted on server but SYNC-ACK packet goes before application receives connected socket.

FYI, I also tried to apply DSCP on server listener socket. But Linux doesn't use that value for SYNC-ACK packets.

Comment: Do you mean SYN packets?

Comment: No I am talking about SYNC_ACK packet which is second packet of TCP 3-way handshake sequence.

Answer (score 0):

from this [page](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/a345e6da-f6d2-4e8d-8c39-74dad58b1879/y), the SYNC_ACK is the same as SYNC which from client.